# How to make my site HTTP to HTTPS. Godaddy domain connecting to AWS (amazon-route53 & amazon-elastic-beanstalk)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, godaddy-api

I need to make my site HTTP to HTTPS. I've connected my site to AWS amazon-elastic-beanstalk to Godaddy using Route53 using nameservers. After connecting Godaddy to AWS using nameservers. I cannot edit my DNS section in GoDaddy anymore. To make my site HTTPS I need to request the certificate in Certificate Manager. To request the certificate we have two-way DNS validation and email validation. I cannot use DNS validation because after connecting my Godaddy site to route53 using nameservers. I can't edit DNS anymore. Please help, how to make my site HTTPS. [Godaddy DNS section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILoNh.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved. I can add DNS CNAME in AWS side.

Comment: Can you provide the solution with more details. for ex : what do you mean by AWS side?

Comment: My problem was when I added aws nameserver in GoDaddy. I can't longer edit DNS in Godaddy. To request for HTTPS certification in Aws Certification Manager I need to use DNS validation. When I look on GoDaddy I can't edit DNS there, so I was confused. Then I understood after adding AWS nameservers in GoDaddy the provision to change DNS CNAME is on AWS hosted zone configuration side

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Route53 here as it is ONLY Domain service. HTTP and HTTPS are unrelated to domains and is protocol dependent. You have to manage these at application layer. Some options for you are:

- Use S3 to re-route your site. http://url -> S3 (reroute to www.url)
- Use CloudFront (My recommendation) built-in feature of redirect http to https
- Handle the HTTP at application layer and use NGINX or something similar to reroute to HTTPS URL